# imagePullSecrets not working when using k3s

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, rancher, k3s

I'm using [k3s](https://k3s.io/) to test my k8s configurations. Sadly, `imagePullSecrets` seems not to work properly.

I've tested the same configuration in [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/) and it works fine.

Example:

I create the secret with:

```
kubectl create secret generic myreg --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=$HOME/.docker/config.json
```

And this is a daemonset example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: foo
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: myreg
      containers:
      - name: foo
        image: whatever/foo:latest
```

The status stays as `ErrImagePull` and running `describe` over the pod it says:

```
  Normal   BackOff    2s    kubelet, localhost  Back-off pulling image "whatever/foo:latest"
  Warning  Failed     2s    kubelet, localhost  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Why Does it not work?

Comment: why do you create a `generic` secret and not a `docker-registry` secret ? check https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod

Comment: hmmmm.... I didn't realized that. Maybe that was my problem. I have to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer in the issue [Document image preloading](https://github.com/rancher/k3s/issues/167).

The imagePullSecrets are not implemented in k3s, but there is an undocumented feature, and you can pull the image manually to get it work.

To do it (as root):

```
# docker pull whatever/foo:latest
# docker save whatever/foo:latest -o /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/images/foo-latest.tgz
```

And then the image will be "downloaded" and installed into k3s.

**Remember** to restart k3s after downloading it.

Comment: imagePullSecrets works with me with k3s 1.0 (with default options, containerd not docker) and with private repos/registry in Gitlab.com.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from [yonsy-solis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5297793/yonsy-solis) solved this for me:

### Replace `generic` with `docker-registry`:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry myreg --from file=.dockerconfigjson=$HOME/.docker/config.json
```

Note that `generic` used to work for me in the past. With some update, this must have changed.

(@yonsy-solis, I don't want to take the credit away from you, but this is so useful that I think it should be a proper answer, rather than just comment)